# Deadlock occurs when using findAll() from JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There was a problem with the implementation of the findAll () methods. When called, Deadlock occurs.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
   /** other fields omitted **/
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Faculty faculty;
 }

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "faculties")
public class Faculty {
   /** other fields omitted **/
   @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FacultyRepository extends JpaRepository<Faculty, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {
}
```

When I call the findAll () method from the controller,

[image: the result is as follows]

I installed all the dependencies between the objects as recommended [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Please tell me how to fix this Deadlock=) Thanks)

Comment: Relationships are not as recommended there. Attribute `mappedBy="faculty"` is missing from `@OneToMany`.

Comment: @MikkoMaunu if set (Attribute mappedBy="faculty") - I get an exception

Comment: You should avoid both side CascadeType.ALL

Comment: @alexvaluiskui that is, i need to delete CascadeType.ALL in Group and Faculty?) just did it, the deadlock remained((

Comment: You question appears to have absoutely nothing to do with Soring Data, JPA or  the database but with an error serializing to JSON, a question that has been asked and answered many times before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: Remove the mapped relationships from the equals and hashCode methods (@EqualsAndHasCode(exclude = {"faculty"}) on class declaration or     @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude on field declaration if using lombok)